# Perform pydantic validation asynchronously

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, aiohttp

I'm creating an API for marketplace with FastAPI where a user can both buy items and sell items. But to sell items, a user has to be registered as a seller. To do this, he is supposed to fulfill *TIN*, *TRRC*, *BIC*, and other banking credentials. Obviously, this data is supposed to be validated. I want it to be validated in my pydantic schemas. To validate, I want to use public API. When I send `GET` request to the API, it returns `HTTP_200` if valid, else `HTTP_400`. To validate each piece of those data I have a separete method in pydantic model. And I want to send async requests to the API with aiohttp. In documentation it is highly recommended to use one session object per the whole application, and do not create a new session with every new request. To solve this problem, I created a class which implements `Singletone` pattern and get session object if exists, or creates it if not and close the session when all done. 
Here is the code of the class:

```
import aiohttp


class HTTPSessionManager:
    _session = None

    @classmethod
    def get_session(cls) -> aiohttp.ClientSession:
        if cls._session is None:
            cls._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        return cls._session

    @classmethod
    async def close_session(cls):
        """
        Session closure
        """
        if cls._session is not None:
            await cls._session.close()
```

Also I have a common method to validate each field for registering as a seller (*BIC*, *TIN*, and so forth). This method takes a URL and a field to validate:

```
from fastapi import HTTPException
from starlette import status

from src.http_session import HTTPSessionManager


async def validate(url: str, obj: str):
    session = HTTPSessionManager.get_session()
    try:

        response = await session.get(url, params={obj: obj})

        if response.status == 200:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, detail=str(e))
    finally:

        await session.close()
```

And this method is supposed to be called in pydantic model like this:

```
class SellerIn(BaseModel):
    mobile: str = Field(regex=r'\b\+?[7,8](\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2})\b')   # group
    company_name: str
    company_description: str
    bank_name: str
    tin: str = Field()
    bic: str
    trrc: str
    an: str
    additional: str = None

    @classmethod
    @field_validator('bic')
    async def validate_tin(cls, value):
        return await validate(obj=value, url='https://htmlweb.ru/api.php?obj=validator&m=bic')
```

And I'm not really sure, if I can use pydantic asynchronously. If I can't, how could I solve the problem considering the fact that I want my request to the public API to run asynchronously. 
P.S. My *python* version is 3.11, *FastAPI* is 0.104.0, *aiohttp* is 3.8.6 and *pydantic* is 2.4.2

I would be very grateful for each response and suggestion.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/857 and https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/7627 ? Did you just try it out with `asyncio.sleep` and see if that works?

Comment: I have seen the first issue, but I suoposed that something my changed for several years after that question was posted. So if not, should I perform this validation in routers instead of pydantic, for example?

Comment: @MihailBury Yes, external validation, such as against a database or another API is best handled in your route function

Comment: It'd be best handled in your service/repository layer if you can't handle it there - I'd try to keep that business logic out of the controller itself.